# Building a set of unique lines in a file efficiently, without storing actual lines in the set

Tags: c++, time-complexity, space-complexity, memory-limit

Recently I was trying to solve the following issue:

I have a very large file, containing long lines, and I need to find and print out all the unique lines in it.

I don't want to use a map or set storing the actual lines, as the file is very big and the lines are long, so this would result in O(N) space complexity with poor constants (where N is the number of lines). Preferably, I would rather generate a set storing the pointers to the lines in the files that are unique. Clearly, the size of such a pointer (8 bytes on 64 bit machine I believe) is generally much smaller than the size of line (1 byte per character I believe) in memory. Although space complexity is still O(N), the constants are much better now. Using this implementation, the file never needs to be fully loaded in memory.

Now, let's say I'll go through the file line by line, checking for uniqueness. To see if it is already in the set, I could compare to all lines pointed by the set so far, comparing character by character. This gives O(N^2*L) complexity, with L the average length of a line. When not caring about storing the full lines in the set, O(N*L) complexity can be achieved, thanks to hashing. Now, when using a set of pointers instead (to reduce space requirements), how can I still achieve this? Is there a neat way to do it? The only thing I can come up with is this approach:

1. Hash the sentence. Store the hash value to  map (or actually: unordered_multimap unordered to get the hashmap style, multi as double keys may be inserted in case of 'false matches').
2. For every new sentence: check if its hash value is already in the map. If not, add it. If yes, compare the full sentences (new one and the one in the unordered map with same hash) character by character, to make sure there is no 'false match'. If it is a 'false match', still add it.

Is this the right way? Or is there a nicer way you could do it? All suggestions are welcome!

And can I use some clever 'comparison object' (or something like that, I don't know much about that yet) to make this checking for already existing sentences fully automated on every unordered_map::find() call?

Comment: Can you give a rough estimation on how many lines your file has and/or the total file size?

Comment: Are you saying that full file is stored in memory elsewhere, so you can point to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution looks fine to me since you are storing O(unique lines) hashes not N, so that's a lower bound.

Since you scan the file line by line you might as well sort the file. Now duplicate lines will be contiguous and you need only check against the hash of the previous line. This approach uses O(1) space but you've got to sort the file first.

Comment: The sorting is indeed interesting, as it enables O(1) space complexity... However, time complexity was O(N) first, but with sorting it would become O(NlgN). 

Btw: if you can't assume anything about the input (which is my case), space complexity is actually O(N), as you have no clue about the number of unique lines...

Answer (score 2):

As @saadtaame's answer says, your space is actually O(unique lines) - depending on your use case, this may be acceptable or not.

While hashing certainly has its merits, it can conceivably have many problems with collisions - and if you can't have false positives, then it is a no-go unless you actually keep the contents of the lines around for checking.

The solution you describe is to maintain a hash-based set. That is obviously the most straightforward thing to do, and yes it would require to maintain all the unique lines in memory. That may or may not be a problem, though. That solution would also the easiest to implement -- what you are trying to do is exactly what any implementation of a (hash-based) set would do. You can just use `std::unordered_set`, and add every line to the set.

Since we are throwing around ideas, you could also use a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) as a substitute for the set. You would maybe save some space, but it still would be O(unique lines).

Answer (score 0):

If there isn't some special structure in the file you can leverage, then definitively go for hashing the lines. This will - by orders of magnitude - be faster than actually comparing each line against each other line in the file.

If your actual implementation is still too slow, you can e.g. limit the hashing to the first portion of each line. This will produce more false positives, but assuming, that most lines will deviate already in the first few words, it will significantly speed up the file processing (especially, if you are I/O-bound).